# Perform action based on callback(true) / callback(false)

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to be able to perform some logic within a callback function based on whether callback(true) or callback(false) was called in the preceeding function.

**Example:**

```
foo.doFunction = function (param, callback)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = param;

    if(a < param)
    {
         callback(false);
    }
    else
    {
         callback(true);
    }
}

foo.doFunction(param, function()
{
     if(true)
     {
     }
     if(false)
     {
     }
});
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible through the use of callbacks?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, though your callback function would need to read the argument by name or using the `arguments` array:

```
foo.doFunction(param, function(myParam)
{
     if(myParam)
     {
     }
     else
     {
     }
});
```